# Multiple-day event date in JabRef

Tags: bibliographies, jabref, date

In `JabRef`, I would like to write the event date, not as a single day, but as a period. Something like:

```
eventdate = {YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM-DD}
eventdate = {From YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM-DD}
```

etc.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If you use `biblatex` (I assume you do, because I am not aware of BibTeX styles using `eventdate`), the correct input for date ranges is `YYYY-MM-DD/YYYY-MM-DD` as per ISO 8601.

Comment: You can use all supported dates from the [biblatex guide](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). See section 2.3.8 for the formats. However JabRef currently does not support a check for correctnes of all possible dates. There's already an issue regarding that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `biblatex` (and that seems like a fair assumption given that none of the `.bst` files available on my system support `eventdate`) you can use ISO 8601 dates, ranges can be given with `/` as range separator

```
eventdate = {YYYY-MM-DD/YYYY-MM-DD},
```

See also §2.3.8 *Date and Time Specifications* of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).